# PyQT4 / QT Creator - How to create a dial with a slider who's free to move every where on the dial?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I used QTCreator to create a slider. Here a picture about the dial I made :

[image: What I have]

I would like to move the slider (which it's the point inside the dial) everywhere inside the dial and not just around it. In fact, I want to change the distant of the slider to the center of the dial, on the same way that we can make it turn around the dial.

For example, I can make the slider (blue dots) moved around the dial but I can't make it moved as green dots :

[image: What I expect]

The goal is to get the value of the rotation (between 0 and 360°), so it's done. And next step, to get the distance of green dots from the center. So I can obtain 2 values for next steps in my project.

Is that possible ?

Here is the widget code of Qt Creator used to make the dial :

```
<widget class="QDial" name="dial">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>300</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="layoutDirection">
     <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="minimum">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="maximum">
     <number>360</number>
    </property>
    <property name="singleStep">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="pageStep">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>180</number>
    </property>
    <property name="sliderPosition">
     <number>180</number>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="wrapping">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, what you already got and what the problem with the remaining part is. Please add pictures and perhaps an [mcve] to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Message updated, I hope more clear now